# How do I disable weapon switching using the right stick in Borderlands 2 VR

Tags: borderlands-2-vr

Borderlands 2 VR has a very irritating setup where if you set your right stick to turn (as you almost certainly want to for seated play) it does not remove the bindings to allow weapon selection using the right stick.  This is super inconvenient as generally you don't want to change weapons when you turn.  There is a sort of workaround of only equipping two weapon slots, but generally speaking, it's useful to be able to equip all four weapons.

Is there any way to disable weapon swapping using the right stick, and just have the B button cycle weapons?  There doesn't seem to be a UI option to do this, but maybe it's achievable by editing config files?

ETA I'm running this on Oculus Quest via Virtual Desktop from Steam.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably achieve that by editing the `.ini` file. I haven't gone that far, but I have tackled the issue where you accidentally switch weapons all the time, see [my post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PicoXR/comments/17e01v0/borderlands_2_vr_controls_fix/).

PS: in an upcoming update of that post I'll also show how to disable up/down altogether or bind different functions to it. ETA: November.

Comment: Would you be able to put some more specifics here about what in the `.ini` file you would suggest editing? I do see the instructions in the linked Reddit post, but without that this answer isn't super useful (and generally it's preferable for answer to be able to stand on its own).

Comment: There's instructions in my post on what to edit in the .ini files to ensure the weapon swapping doesn't happen by accident, but it will bind next weapon to up and previous weapon to down on the right controller (weapon swap is B). I'm fine with that binding, but if you prefer different usage/binding for up/down, can you tell me what you'd prefer instead? I'll see what I can do, but I'm away from home now so that may take me a week or 2 to get back on. I'll make sure to include at that time also how to disable the up/down functionality altogether as the OP asked.